# VMware ESXi - assign IP to Windows vm

Tags: windows, networking, vmware-esxi

I have a VMware ESXi 6.0 server and I uploaded a Windows 7 vm on it.

I can't make internet working, I bought some IPs and they sent me this email (I don't even understand French very well):

```
Si vous utilisez ce bloc dans une baie virtuelle ou dans un Cloud Dédié, il faut libérer les adresses suivantes :

IP de réseau              : xx.yy.50.160
IP de passerelle           : xx.yy.50.162 (non utilisable)
Ip de broadcast            : xx.yy.50.163

Utilisez alors le masque de sous-réseau 255.255.255.252.


Pour votre information, votre bloc a les caractéristiques suivantes :

xx.yy.50.160/30
IP de réseau      : xx.yy.50.160
IP de broadcast    : xx.yy.50.163
Ip de passerelle   : xx.yy.50.162
Netmask            : 255.255.255.252
```

I put the following in the Windows ipv4 settings:

```
IP address: xx.yy.50.160
subnet mask: 255.255.255.252
Default gateway: xx.yy.50.162
```

But I get the error "The combination of ip address and subnet mask is invalid", with the IP .161 it saves the settings, but the Internet doesn't work...

the DNS servers were 4.2.2.5 and 4.2.2.6, I tried to change it to the Google's ones but nothing changed.

What must I do?

Comment: **.160** is the network address and isn't usable by hosts. **.161** is the only host ip address available to use. Your ESXi host isn't a router and doesn't route traffic, which is the crux of your problem.

Comment: I really don't understand, I bought 4 ips but I can only use 1? The host had only a single ip address, how can I change it?

Comment: I added the ip in the ESXi control panel, now Windows says that `another computer on this network has the same IP address as this computer`... Where can I find some help? I didn't expect it was so complicated

Comment: Funny, OVH sends me email in English, including this particular message template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, I "assigned a virtual MAC to failover ip" as described [here](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-virtual-mac/) for OVH, and I put the MAC address of the VM to the .161 IP

After this, it started working...

Answer (score 4):

The x.x.50.160 IP is the network address, you cannot use it on any of your hosts.

The only IP you can use is the x.x.50.161 on your host.
Your gateway has to be the x.x.50.162 IP.

Comment: The host has a totally different ip address, so it can't work? How can I change the ip of the host?